# Modify login/register page - WooCommerce wpbakery

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, wpbakery

Disclaimer: I'm still in a learning phase with WP.

I bought a theme from the marketplace for me to test and play around with, but I am stuck with an issue where I am trying to modify the login page. I am unable to find any options of where I can modify it. Is there a static html file that I would have to look for?

I'm looking to remove the text at the bottom of this screenshot:

[image]

If there is a way to restrict the section that ask for "username or email address" to only email addresses I would like to make that rule as well.

This Theme is using WP-bakery if that makes any difference.

Any advise would be appreciated.